# Poker cards in Mandarin

Tags: mandarin, games

In Cantonese:

A = 煙; a pair of A = 煙啤(pair)

K = 傾; a pair of K = 傾啤(pair)

Q = 囡; a pair of Q = 囡啤(pair)

J = 積; a pair of J = 積啤(pair)

10-3 are called 10仔 - 3仔; pair of 10-3 is called 10仔啤 - 3仔啤/10一啤 - 3一啤

2 = 弟(dee); a pair of 2 = 弟啤(dee pair)

I know different regions have different names for cards, I just want to know what Standard Mandarin (普通話) call them

*I presume a pair of 10 is 十一對 and a pair of 3 is 三一對*

*poker card in Mandarin is 扑克牌, and Cantonese call it 啤(pair)牌*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are standard names for them in standard mandarin. But we always say in Mandarin number+classifier+noun，so it's 一对三 (a pair of 3)，一对十 (a pair of 4)。noun+number+classifier is used in classical Chinese, and many contemporary dialects.

While JQKA are written as the English letter, the names are highly colloquial and regional. For example, in Sichuanese Mandarin, a popular set of names are 勾/钩 (gou1, J), 框 (kuang1, Q), ke3 (K, this is how Sichuanese pronounce the letter K), 帽/冒 尖 (mao4 jian1 A, equally used). There's also a less used name for Q which is 圈(quan1).

An interesting phenomenon in Sichuanese Mandarin is the wide use of reduplication. In this case, when used alone and the number is specified, 勾/钩, 框/圈, ke3, 帽/冒 尖 are usually in reduplication, for example, when you play a J, you could accompany it by saying 勾勾。In the number+classifier+noun construction, a string of card names, or 1-10, reduplication is not used, for example, 一对勾，十钩框ke2帽。

This set of name is also widely used in other parts of China, especially 勾、圈、kei4 (the standard mandarin pronunciation for K)、尖, and people from almost all regions are able to understand. So if I need to say their names in standard Mandarin, this set would be my choice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133342/discussion-on-answer-by-lilysirius-poker-cards-in-mandarin).